# MySQL connection server-client

Tags: php, mysql, connection, freebsd, centos6

I have some troubles with connection between game server and web server.
Gameserver is running FreeBSD 9.3, Mysql5.5 and Webserver is using Centos 6.5 .

Sometimes connection it's successfull but unexpected after few refreshes I receive this error:

```
access denied for user 'root'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password yes)
```

I've tried without this file but the same result with it or without: my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
query_cache_limit=5M
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=1
max_connections=1500
interactive_timeout=100
wait_timeout=50
connect_timeout=10
thread_cache_size=128
key_buffer=200M
join_buffer=1M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1536
sort_buffer_size=18M
read_buffer_size=18M
max_connect_errors=10
thread_concurrency=2
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
server-id=1
tmp_table_size=32M
max_heap_table_size=32M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer=128M
read_buffer=10M
write_buffer=10M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=128M
sort_buffer=128M
read_buffer=10M
write_buffer=10M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

[image: MySQL user preview]

[image: MySQL privileges preview(all privilleges active)]

Comment: What could help, is connecting to another user, instead of "root". Some servers may block connections to "root" by default.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried first time with user `Administrator` but result was the same. For server secure I want to use  'user'@'specific IP'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your MySQL 'user' actual privileges
Take a notice that you need to provide the actual IP address of client connection, so your user can connect to the server: 'user'@'192.168.1.2' for example.

Or you can allow this user to connect from any IP using 'user'@'%' statement.

Can you show your privileges table?
Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/mysql-account-privileges.html) to know more about MySQL privileges, it could help.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'5.154.240.166' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*0EC4AE6282E803E81E2329FB776F56F85413BE0D' WITH GRANT OPTION 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+